# What type of switch would disconnect 3 separate lines?

Tags: switches

What type of switch would disconnect 3 separate lines? I just can't think of what it should be named.

If possible a suggestion of a specific item would be welcome.

Comment: Other than a triple pole switch?

Comment: or a three pole switch (or more poles if you leave some unused!)

Comment: TPST Switch....

Comment: if you want something with a crazy number of poles also look for a "PO type 1000 lever key" - you find them kicking about on ebay etc. you can do crazy logic with those (they are often two separate 4PCO switches in one unit, with up and down positions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A triple pole switch would be what you are looking for in this case.  You could also use a single-pole triple-throw switch.  Just take a look at the picture below:

[image: Switch Types]

You can use only one line at the time which I am assuming is what you would want to do.  Look for relays that are triple-throw if you want more information.

But if you look to disconnect three lines at the same time, you would need to look for a triple-pole single-throw type of device.  Take a look at the one shown below:

[image: TPST/3PST Switch]

This option would make more sense if you are trying to disconnect all the lines at the same time.

Comment: The last drawing answers the original question **almost** perfectly. And if you erase the short circuit on the top line, it *would* be perfect. ;-)

Comment: @MikeWaters: Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Would a 3PDT do the trick? Three poles, two positions - on and off.

[image]

Comment: This would work with the info. OP gave. However, 3PST/TPST switches do exist, and are often less expensive while still fulfilling the requirement to "disconnect 3 lines."